# Can you only gain the benefits of a healing potion by drinking it?

Tags: dnd-5e, healing, potions

My PCs will find in a body of a half-orc an unmarked bottle with a *potion of healing*. What if they think that this is a poison which drows often use in my campaign? They would pour the bottle on their swords.

Does a *potion of healing* have a different effect if applied on an open wound, such as when the PCs slice enemies with it?

The [*potion of healing*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/potion-of-healing)'s description states:

> You regain hit points when you drink this potion.

I assume that using it differently it has no effect, but maybe there is some information about it deeper. If not, I can always improvise, but maybe it's better to let it be with no effect.

Comment: For anyone wondering, ["per os"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/per_os) means "orally; by mouth". Also, you should limit yourself to one question per post; I've edited out the secondary question about identifying a potion.

Answer (score 17):

RAW, the effects only apply when it is consumed "[per os](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oral_administration#:%7E:text=Per%20os%20(%2F%CB%8Cp%C9%9C%CB%90r,for%20example%2C%20caries%20prophylaxis).)". (Emphasis mine).

> You regain 2d4 + 2 Hit Points when you **drink this potion**

[Source](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Potion%20of%20Healing#content)

Comment: At least in previous versions they called out that it was the act of quaffing the potion that activated its magic. Even if you didn't have a digestive tract you could benefit, assuming you could benefit from healing magic.

Comment: Raises an interesting question about what would happen if emptied several potions into a font and then held a monk's head under it. Would he get healed as he drowned? Sure, water is going into his mouth and down his throat, but is he _drinking_ it? (I may ask this as a standalone question at a later date)

Comment: Woah, hold the phone - "_A character who drinks the magical red fluid in this vial regains 2d4+2 hit points. Drinking **or administering** a potion takes an action_" - I guess in my case I would be administering (or admonking hoho) the potion.

Comment: @RyanfaeScotland: There are optional potion-mixing rules in the DMG, though I don't know if they'd apply if you're "mixing" the same potions together.